# How to fix <td> being printed five times instead of 2 (PHP)?

Tags: javascript, php, css, html

I need help with this for loop. I want it to print controls on the side of the row for each item listed but its listing 5 instead of 2 sets of controls.

```php
<tbody>
<?php
//get list of supplies
$numOfRows = 0;

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM supplies");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
    $numOfRows ++;
  }
 //controls
  for ($i = 0;$i <= $numOfRows; $i++) {
    echo '<td><a><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a><a><i class="fas fa-trash-alt">
 </i></a></td>';                                          
  }
}
echo '</tr>';
?>
</tbody>
```

Comment: The anchors your `PHP` is generating are invalid.

Comment: Oh yea. They don't do anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

review your code, second for is using numOfRows variable which is not right at all, you are iterating as many rows your table have is not just 5 times, if you have 100 records then you'll see that TD printed 100 times, BTW you can put those 2 buttons into a single  TD that way you will not need the second for at all

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another loop required for controls. Try this i hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```
<?php

$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM supplies");

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
    echo '<td><a><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a><a><i class="fas fa-trash-alt">
      </i></a></td>';
    }                                          
  }
}
echo '</tr>';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want each item on it's own row showing the item (`$item`) in the first column and the edit/delete links in the 2nd column you only need the `while` to go through each row found.

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';
  echo '<td>
        <a><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a>
        <a><i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i></a>
        </td>';
  echo '</tr>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // In your code you have the 
 // "<tr>" element inside of your loop. 
 // It needs to come before your loop. Try the code below

// This is where you need <tr>
 echo "<tr>";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // this is where you had tr // echo <tr>
  foreach ($row as $item) {
    echo '<td>' . $item . '</td>';`enter code here`
    $numOfRows ++;
  }
 //controls
  for ($i = 0;$i <= $numOfRows; $i++) {
    echo '<td><a><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a><a><i class="fas fa-trash-alt">
 </i></a></td>';                                          
  }
}
echo '</tr>';
```